# Oracle Jdeveloper - IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jdeveloper, ioerror

I'm a rookie with JDeveloper and I'm trying to use JDBC. I create a database project with its database diagram to make offline database but when I tried to create a new database conection and test it this error appears:'IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection'.

I searched it on google and appeared some things like alter some archives (tnsnames.ora for example) but I can't find them in JDeveloper folder, I also see something about tnsping but I didn't find it either. I tried to reinstall it but it didn't work. My JDeveloper version is: JDeveloper studio edition 12.1.2.0.0 (32bits).

Someone knows how to make it work? What I'm doing wrong? I'll be gratefull with any clue you can lend me. Thank you.

Comment: Can you paste the code you have so far?

Comment: There's no code, my professor tell us to make a database diagram, drag and drop the elements we need and when the structure is created then go to create a new connection (in tools/database). It's supposed to create the code after doing all of this. Sorry.

Comment: What settings have you used for the connection? Were you given settings by your professor, for an actual database to connect to so you can run the object creation against that?

Comment: Duplicate of [sqldeveloper error message: Network adapter could not establish the connection error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025014/sqldeveloper-error-message-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection-e), and many others.

Comment: Can you connect to the database outside JDeveloper, e.g. using sqldeveloper or other database client. It seems to be a general connection problem.