# SQL Developer How Fix issue ? "Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have installed sql developer oracle on windows 10, but when I try to create new databse and connect to it I have problem "Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection" , Something is missed in my installation list setups.
[image]

Comment: these can be the possibiliteis :-You are using the wrong URL

- The wrong port number or IP address (or DNS host name) was used

- The listener is not configured properly

- The listener process (service) is not running.  You can re-start it with the "lsnrctl start" command or on Windows by starting the listener service.

Comment: "lsnrctl start"   I tryed but cmd says: 'lsnrctl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,      operable program or batch file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqldeveloper error message: Network adapter could not establish the connection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025014/sqldeveloper-error-message-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection-e)

Comment: on windows 10 listener service for oracle needs to be started

Answer (score 1):

> but when I try to create new databse and connect to it I have problem
>   ...Something is missed in my installation list setups

So, keywords, 'create new database' -

That screen does not CREATE a database. It only allows you to create a connection to an existing database.

So you need to get a database first.

You have some free and easy options, which I talk about [here](https://medium.com/oracledevs/i-installed-oracle-sql-developer-now-what-71230b9c9303).

Also, can you share your installation setup list, so we can see what you've done? It's possible you DO have a database.

But, seeing you're trying to connect as 'root' - I doubt it. That is an OS user, not an Oracle DB user - which on a new system would be something like 'SYS' or 'SYSTEM.'